# The meaning of UK dependent visa application centre correspondence?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I have applied for the UK dependent visa my wife has a European passport and I have Indian passport.

We have given all documents and today is 8th day and the UK visa centre has sent me an e-mail saying that the uk visa application has been processed and a decision has been made. your passport and documents will be dispatched via VFS.

What does it mean?  Is it that my visa has been granted?

Answer (score 4):

It likely means just that 'your passport and documents will be dispatched'.  It's  a stock email that gets produced automatically when they're finished processing, and rather than have to customise it for each person with results, it's just to let you know your documents are on their way back.

Unfortunately, this means you'll likely have to wait for your documents/passport to arrive in the mail before you know the outcome of the decision :/

Comment: +1, but please remove the words 'almost certainly'

Answer (score 1):

These emails are just a notification that your passports are on the way. There is no way to tell whether you got the visas or not prior to actually receiving them. Good luck!